# MongoDB user creation timestamp extract from where

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

How to identify when a local SCRAM-SHA-256 user has been created in mongoDB database sharded cluster?

Comment: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151892/how-do-i-find-the-creation-date-of-a-user-in-mongodb

Comment: this was my worst nightmare ...  :( :)

Comment: indeed, the user management in mongodb is kind of baby's first attempt...